# SQL - running total with max

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have a bunch of transactions (deposits/withdrawals) that i want to track a running balance for, but the trick is this - there is an automation of the balance that will skim money off when the balance goes over a certain balance so that not too much cash is left in this account ( think risk, security etc).I'm trying to work out the optimal level this 'skimming' should occur so that we don't have to top the account up either.

Target - using $1000 skim balance

| ID | Type | Amount | Running Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Deposit | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | Deposit | 150 | 850 |
| 3 | Deposit | 1500 | 1000 (capped) |
| 4 | Withdrawal | 100 | 900 |
| 5 | Deposit | 500 | 1000 ( capped) |
| 6 | Deposit | 150 | 1000 (still capped) |

Appreciate any assistance that you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved by `recursive cte`

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Id, Type, Amount, Amount AS Balance FROM Transactions WHERE Id = 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Transactions.Id, Transactions.Type, Transactions.Amount, 
        CASE 
            WHEN
              CASE 
                  WHEN Transactions.Type = 'D' THEN CTE.Balance + Transactions.Amount 
                  ELSE CTE.Balance - Transactions.Amount 
              END > 1000
            THEN 1000
            ELSE
              CASE 
                  WHEN Transactions.Type = 'D' THEN CTE.Balance + Transactions.Amount 
                  ELSE CTE.Balance - Transactions.Amount 
              END
        END
    FROM Transactions 
    JOIN CTE ON CTE.Id + 1 = Transactions.Id
) SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Where we loop trow table rows and apply condition after each balance update

[SQL online editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/00ddca94f9f9bf61bc5494360d530420/)

Result:

```
+====+======+========+=========+
| Id | Type | Amount | Balance |
+====+======+========+=========+
| 1  | D    | 300    | 300     |
+----+------+--------+---------+
| 2  | D    | 400    | 700     |
+----+------+--------+---------+
| 3  | D    | 500    | 1000    |
+----+------+--------+---------+
| 4  | W    | 300    | 700     |
+----+------+--------+---------+
| 5  | D    | 200    | 900     |
+----+------+--------+---------+
| 6  | W    | 500    | 400     |
+----+------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Getting this error on SQL Server - Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Balance" of recursive query "CTE".

Comment: All good - i had to cast everthing to the same format. Its now working - thank you